# How does upper_bound work with custom object type val?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++17

I am currently learning about upper_bound algorithm in c++ and things are quite easy if the third parameter val is of type Integer. However, i came across an exammple with custom type val and things got a little confusing.
Sample code.

```
class Pocket
{
public:
    int value;
    Pocket(int value) : value(value) {};
    bool operator < (const Pocket& right) const
    {
        return value < right.value;
    }

    int getValue() const
    {
        return value;
    }
};

bool Compare(const Pocket &left, const Pocket &right)
{
    return int (left.getValue() > right.getValue());
}

void main()
{
    int a[] = { 3, 9, 2, 4, 4 };
    std::deque<Pocket> d(a, a + 5);
    std::sort(d.begin(), d.end(), Compare);
    std::deque<Pocket>::iterator it = std::upper_bound(d.begin(), d.end(), Pocket(2));
}
```

The resulting iterator *it* will point to the element with value 9. How?

Comment: Looks like undefined behavior. The list is not sorted in the same order as the upper_bound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program has undefined behaviour. The range you pass to upper bound must be sorted by `<` (for the three argument overload).

Comment: no not necessarily by `<`. `std::upper_bound` takes a comparator that has to result in same order as the container is sorted already

Comment: @idclev463035818 the three argument form uses `<`

Comment: afaik it doesn't even have to be the same comparator as long as the container is sorted with respect to the comparator used with `std::upper_bound`

Comment: oh ok sorry, my bad. Didn't read carefully enough. Still, adding that would also show OP how to solve it

Comment: oh got it. The comparator messes up the behavior of upper bound, changed it to < and got the expected result. Thanks!